# Does google provide a test API key that I can use with Google Maps Javascript API?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Google provide a test API key for Google reCAPTCHA that can be used for automated testing etc. (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq).

Is there a similar test API key for Google Maps JavaScript API?

Thanks

Comment: You can test either with no key (it is not required) or with any test (browser) key you want to create in the [google api console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials), see ["Get A Key" in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)

Comment: Thanks, it was not clear to me that the key is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation:
[**Google Maps JavaScript API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/)
[How to **get a key**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#premium-key)

Create an API key:
[Credentials](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)